# Selecting from tables with two conditions

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have three tables with the stated columns:

```
- tblEmployee
  - EmployeeID FK
  - FirstName
  - LastName
  - IsActive

- tblEmployeeMapping
  - ID FK
  - EmployeeID
  - ManagerID

- tblManager
  - ManagerID
  - ManagerName
```

I need SQL select statements that will select employees that are under the ManagerID and  which the tblEmployee.IsActive = 1 (TRUE).

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
SELECT e.FirstName, e.LastName, m.ManagerName 
  FROM tblEmployee e INNER JOIN tblEmployeeMapping em ON e.EmployeeID = em.EmployeeID 
       INNER JOIN tblManager m ON em.ManagerID = m.ManagerID
WHERE e.IsActive = 1
```

and if you want to limit the employees to a specific manager, you can change the where statement to:

```
WHERE e.IsActive = 1
  AND em.ManagerID = @ManagerID
```

where `@ManagerID` is a parameter that contains the manager's ID.